# How to activate the window you're looking at through your webcam

Tags: windows

Is there a way for Windows to activate the window that you are looking at so you don't have to click on it any more with your mouse? So if I for example have two windows open (Chrome + Excel) on two screens. When I look at the Excel window it's automatically activated and I can directly type there. Then when I look at chrome, then that window is automatically activated.

Especially for people with big screens or multiple monitors, it's really handy and would save a lot of time. I tried looking for it but I couldn't find it.  It doesn't surprise me however it isn't included in Windows 8. Even after 6 six years of having browsers with tabs, they still didn't think of including it in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Pretty interesting related article from Stanford University: http://hci.stanford.edu/cstr/reports/2007-02.pdf

Comment: @Moses indeed. But what bothers me that that's an article of 2007 and now it's 2013 and still there's nothing. The technology is there, Micorsoft has the money to create it but they rather spend it on transforming their productive os into a computer-smart-phone kinda thing that no one likes.

Comment: The problem with developing techonology like this is that A) honestly, not that many people are terribly interested in it yet B) it doesn't work well enough yet for it to not be annoying to the average user. Microsoft is the last company I would expect to develop something like this, and mobile is a big money-maker right now. A **lot** of people are into mobile devices currently, it isn't true to say no one likes it.

Comment: @Moses I want an OS that is productive and clean where things are done smart. I got my phone for all the fancy stuff. I guess if this is the current development my only option is to switch over to Ubuntu. Before all your (inactive) network were just saved in a nice little menu, now the inactive ones are hidden and only viewable through cmd. And why you can't specify IP settings for a certain network, why at the adapter? It doesn't make sense to do it there.

Comment: @Moses Before to start a program you could just press Windows key, type the name in start and press enter. Now you go to a big screen where sometimes your previous search is still there. Even shutting down the system has become a hassle. And i'm not even talking about windows taking over the system for a restart whether the user likes it or not and potentially losing a lot of work. Shouldn't the system's vulnerability be the user's concern? It's been like six years browsers have tabs, still windows explorer has none :s Pff never mind I could go on forever, ubuntu is the way to go i guess...

Comment: though it's too bad because C#, CRL and Visual Studio are three brilliant master pieces

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can get *most* of the way there, as long as your eyes follow your mouse pointer...

Windows has a little-known feature which will automatically activate the window under your mouse, without having to click on it, a nice usability enhancement borrowed from UNIX systems of old (and still in use today).

You can find this in **Control Panel** > **Ease of Access** > **Change how your mouse works**.

[image: Ease of Access Center]

In this way, simply moving the mouse to the other screen would be sufficient to switch to the window.

Comment: Yeah I already knew of that feature but after seriously trying it out for a couple of months I decided it's more of a hassle as it gives a lot of false (accidental) positives.

Comment: After 20 years on Linux I'm used to it. :) There's a registry hack you can find at a bunch of different web sites to make it wait longer before raising the window, which will probably help with that. Try 500 to 750 ms.